# 502 Bad Gateway nginx (1.9.7) in Homestead [ Laravel 5 ]

Tags: nginx, laravel-5, vagrant, homestead

Did google and various other search engines but still could not sort it out. 
Here is my scenario:

> Larave 5 on homestead

1) `ps -eo pid,comm,euser,supgrp | grep nginx`
[following is the output ]

> 2333 nginx           root     root
>    2335 nginx           vagrant  adm,cdrom,sudo,dip,www-data,plugdev,lpadmin,sambashare,vagrant

2) Based on some search result, did make the following on : `/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d`

> listen.owner = www-data 
>   listen.group = www-data 
>   listen.mode = 0660

3) Output with sudo service php7.0-fpm restart

> - Restarting PHP 7.0 FastCGI Process Manager php-fpm7.0                                                                                                                     [ OK ]

4) Output with `sudo service nginx restart`

> nginx stop/waiting 
>   nginx start/running, process 2650

5)output with :

```
sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart
```

> - Restarting nginx nginx                                                                                                                                                    [fail]

`6)output with:` `tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log`

```
> 2015/12/26 15:35:23 [notice] 2088#2088: signal process started
2015/12/26 15:45:23 [notice] 2266#2266: signal process started
2015/12/26 15:45:23 [alert] 2095#2095: *9 open socket #3 left in connection 5
2015/12/26 15:45:23 [alert] 2095#2095: aborting
2015/12/26 15:49:02 [alert] 2303#2303: *1 open socket #3 left in connection 3
2015/12/26 15:49:02 [alert] 2303#2303: aborting
2015/12/26 16:00:39 [notice] 2475#2475: signal process started
2015/12/26 16:02:25 [notice] 2525#2525: signal process started
2015/12/26 16:03:08 [notice] 2565#2565: signal process started
2015/12/26 16:14:45 [notice] 2645#2645: signal process started
```

`
I am just having bad time with this 502 Bad Gateway

```
> nginx/1.9.7
```

and php

```
> PHP 7.0.1-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+2 (cli) ( NTS )
```

`
If anyone can please help me move on with this situation, that would be great. And, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally solved this [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/502-bad-gateway-nginx-197-in-homestead-laravel-5). I want to thank Miguel from laracast discussion.

You need to change your configuration file under:

```
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled
```

> change line *fastcgi_pass* for

```
 fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
```

**php7.0-fpm.sock** is located under:

```
/var/run/php
```

Since the new VM uses php 7.* and your configuration file might have the php location for 5.6 version.

Then restart Nginx and PHP

```
sudo service nginx restart

sudo service php7.*-fpm restart
```

*7.3 and the xdebug version in Homestead 8.*.* are incompatible. Further info found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54373498/4002133)*

Comment: Just to verify. You mean the line should be changed too:  fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock; ?

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me. fastcgi_pass unix was pointed at a file that did not exist.

Comment: This helped me: https://github.com/laravel/homestead/issues/929#issuecomment-415474971

Comment: For me, the file under `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` was not writable so I ran `sudo service php7.4-fpm restart` and it created the file `/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock`

Answer (score 1):

try this in **/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf**

```
listen.owner = nginx
listen.group = nginx
listen.mode = 0660
```

finally restart **php7.0-fpm**

```
service php7.0-fpm restart
```

Answer (score 1):

I've got same error, 502 Bad Gateway (Ngix 1.blablabla)

It's **EASY** to solve it.

just type into your terminal.

if your VM is running:

```
vagrant reload --provision
```

else:

```
vagrant halt
```

and later:

```
vagrant up --provision
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem ... and solved it in an easy way:

If you use composer, just replace old:

```
laravel/homestead (v2.*)
```

with:

```
laravel/homestead (v3.0.1)
```

Comment: I had laravel/homestead (v3.0.1) while I had the issue. May be in your case it was an issue with laravel/homestead version.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the sites property after provisioning the Homestead box, you should re-run `vagrant reload --provision` to update the Nginx configuration on the virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my story I installed fresh latest homestead and try to run my Laravel 5.4 project but after a day of debugging so gave custom php for my project . This is how it work.

```
 1. vi Homestead.yaml
 2. sites:
    - map: homestead.test
      to: /home/vagrant/code/my-project/public
      php: "7.1"
```

> php 7.1 works from Laravel 5.4 to 5.7

```
 3. vagrant up --provision
```